# Redirect/Refresh Page Using Dynamic Action - Oracle Apex 21.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page (`Page 7`) where user accounts can be created. When a user clicks the `Add User` button, the user goes through a `Create New User Account` flow. This flow follows 3 steps:

- Step 1: `User Info` modal (`Page 10`) displays to enter user information, on `Next` save & branch to `Step 2`
- Step 2: `User Roles` modal  (`Page 11`) displays to assign authorization role(s) to user, on `Done` branch to `Step 3`
- Step 3: Confirmation modal  (`Page 12`) displays showing the user info and some metadata and confirmation that `New User Account Created`

When the user clicks the `Close` button in `Step 3`, I would like:

- The `Step 3` dialog  (`Page 12`) to close
- The parent page, `User Main`, (`Page 7`) to redirect/reload passing in the new username to populate the underlying reports on `Page 7` for this new user account.

Since there is no submit action (`PROCESS`) in `Step 3` - it is just presenting data - I assumed I can not use a branch like Steps 1 and 2. I need to rely on a Dynamic Action. So I tried setting up a DA triggered on the `Dialog Closed` event that `Executes Server-side Code`:

```
DECLARE
  vc_Page7_URL  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  vcPage7_URL := apex_page.get_url(
    p_page   => 7,
    p_items  => 'P7_USERNAME',
    p_values => :P12_USERNAME
  );

  apex_util.redirect_url(
    p_url => vc_Page7_URL
  );
END;
```

This is not working as I expect. I'm obviously overlooking something here. I log the url in the code above to the debug stack and the url is being generated correctly, but I'm not getting a redirect to `Page 7`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that will ever work - you can't do a redirect from within pl/sql in a dynamic action process. The pl/sql code is running in the background and cannot redirect the page. There are 2 options

1. Change true action on page 7 to submit page and add a branch to redirect to the url of your choice
2. Redirect using javascript (google it, you'll find several links on that)

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'll modify to use javascript DA (`apex.navigation.redirect`). I'll circle back with results and mark your answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious what would `apex_util.redirect_url` be used for then?

Comment: It's like a programmatical branch, needs to be executed in pl/sql process, either before rendering (before header) or after submit. As a test, create a page process before header (on another page than page 1) with source ```apex_util.redirect_url(p_url => apex_page.get_url(p_page => 1));``` and observe you'll be redirected to page 1 when you access that page

Comment: ok, so the issue wasn't that i was trying to redirect in PL/SQL. It was more that I was trying to redirect in PLSQL "in a Dynamic Action" instead of in an "APEX Process". Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Way apex works is that a page is rendered and then submitted. page processes can be executed and control the page flow at those points only.

Answer (score 2):

Per @koen's recommendation, I changed the above code to be 2 TRUE actions under the `Close Dialog` event that is attached to the `Click` event of the `Done` button:

1. `Execute Server-side Code`:

```sql
BEGIN
 -- i created a hidden page item to hold the URL
 :P12_REDIRECT_URL := apex_page.get_url(
   p_page   => 7,
   p_items  => 'P7_USERNAME',
   p_values => :P12_USERNAME
 );
END;
```

2. `Execute JavaScript Code`:

```js
let url = $v("P12_REDIRECT_URL");
apex.navigation.redirect(url);
```