# How to use Javascript to redirect to a page in Oracle APEX application without any parameters?

Tags: oracle-apex

In my application I have a ‘main’ table for projects which has a bunch of child tables. I have a delete button that enables the end-user to delete a project. The ‘cascade delete’ will delete the corresponding records from the child tables but I also have dynamic actions set for the delete button that invoke PL/SQL code handle deletion from the junction tables (m:m relationships). All that is left now is to go to the homepage after deletion but for whatever reason I am unable to implement this. I have tried using a branch to navigate to the homepage after processing but it is not working.

Would someone be able to help with the javascript code that will redirect to the homepage? I was planing on adding this javascript as another ‘True’ action once the ‘delete’ button is pressed. I do not need to pass any parameters through the javascript, merely to navigate to page 1 of the application.

I am using APEX version 5.1.3.00.05.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you debugged the application to see why the branch isn't working?  You could use `apex_util.redirect_url` but if branching is working, that implies that there is likely some sort of issue on the page that should be identified and resolved.  It may be impacting more than just branching

Comment: You could also add an action of "Submit" as last action in the dynamic action. Then use a branch to redirect to home page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect/Refresh Page Using Dynamic Action - Oracle Apex 21.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195444/redirect-refresh-page-using-dynamic-action-oracle-apex-21-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple js code to redirect the page.

Put this js in your True DA.

```
let url = "https://yourdomain/app_name/f?p=XXX:YY:"+$v('pInstance')+":::::";
// if you want to redirect it in the same page
window.location = url;
// if you want to open it in a new tab
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Replace -

1. Your domain
2. Your app name
3. XXX = app id
4. YY = your home page no
5. Choose window.location or window.open